# Async/await while array destructing

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'd like the data inside `Promise.all` to be resolved before I actually do the array destructing:

```js
const function = async (one, two) => {
  const [_one, _two] = await Promise.all([
    one.map(translate), // translate is async
    two.map(translate),
  ])

  console.log(_one, _two)
}

const translate = async (data) => getTranslation(data) // getTranslation is async, an API call
```

Right now, the `console.log` gives me `Promise` instead of actual data

Comment: why do you use `await` on a function that is already returning an promise

Comment: What line do you have in mind, 2nd? I've followed: https://www.dalejefferson.com/articles/2018-02-06-async-await-promise-all-array-destructuring/

Comment: [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) expects an iterable of `Promise`s and not an array of arrays (with `Promise`s)

Comment: `translate` is asyn *however*, you don't put the result of it in `Promise.all` - you put the result of `one.map(translate)` which is an *array*, rather than a promise.

Comment: ```[ ...one.map(translate),...two.map(translate)]```

Comment: @Eldar this produces a completely different results.

Comment: @VLAZ would you care to elaborate on that? What's the issue with Eldar's comment?

Comment: @stack that will enumerate both arrays into `Promises` but the final result won't be an array of 2 arrays. It will be an array of combined results from one and two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) expects an array of promises. However, you give it an array of just two arrays *each of which* holds promises. The method is not recursive.

You need to change your code in order to only await the contents of the arrays:

```js
const fn = async (one, two) => {
  const [_one, _two] = [
      await Promise.all(one.map(translate)),
      await Promise.all(two.map(translate))
  ];

  console.log(_one, _two);
}

const translate = async (data) => getTranslation(data);

//mock an API call
function getTranslation(data) {
  return Promise.resolve(`${data}-translated`);
}

fn(["a", "b"], ["x", "y"]);
```

You can generalise this code to handle many arrays that are going to be mapped asynchronously with this sort of function

```js
const fn = async (one, two) => {
  const [_one, _two] = await asyncMapMultiple(translate, [one, two]);

  console.log(_one, _two);
}

const translate = async (data) => getTranslation(data);

//mock an API call
function getTranslation(data) {
  return Promise.resolve(`${data}-translated`);
}

async function asyncMapMultiple(asyncMapper, arrays) {
  return Promise.all( //produce a promise that resolves when everything is finished
    arrays.map(arr => Promise.all(arr.map(asyncMapper))) //map each array asynchronously
  );
}

fn(["a", "b"], ["x", "y"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`one.map(translate)` returns a **Promise Array**.
You have to use `Promise.all` to convert it to a **Promise**.

```js
one // Element[]
one.map(translate) // Promise<Element>[]
Promise.all(one.map(translate)) // Promise<Element[]>
```

In conclusion, you have to use `Promise.all` twice:

```js
const function = async (one, two) => {
  const [_one, _two] = await Promise.all([
    Promise.all(one.map(translate)), // <<
    Promise.all(two.map(translate)), // <<
  ])

  console.log(_one, _two)
}
```

Comment: interesting idea.

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all` expect an array of promises and not a normal array of arrays. It should be a flatten array and not a nested one.

What you can do is have 2 `Promise.all()` (if you want to segregate `one` and `two`):

```
const function = async (one, two) => {
 const _one = await Promise.all(one.map(translate));
 const _two = await Promise.all(two.map(translate));

 console.log(_one, _two)
}
```

If you really want to combine them and use array destruction then you have to flatten them first and merge them,

```
await Promise.all([...one.map(translate), ...two.map(translate)]);
```

however this will cause some problems when you want to segregate the data as you are not sure how many arrays will be returned, unless you have some sort of key on each results.